# Type missinng in React Typescript Axios Response

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-typescript, react-query

I'm trying to write an API service in a React app, using Axios and Typescript.

Below is my code:

Interface for Helper API Class

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

export interface PlatformResponse {
    platform: {
        id: string
        image: string
        name: string
    }[]
}

export interface Platform {
    getPlatformResponse: () => Promise<AxiosResponse<PlatformResponse>>
}
```

My Platform Class

```
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

class Platforms implements Platform {
    async getPlatformResponse(): Promise<AxiosResponse<PlatformResponse>> {
        const path = 'http://localhost:8080/api/platforms'
        const method = 'get'
        const result = await httpRequest({ path, method })
        return result
    }
}

const PlatformsAPI = new Platforms()
export default PlatformsAPI
```

I'm using the react-query library for fetching data, and the code below

```
const useGetPlatforms = () => {
    console.log('sdfd')
    return useQuery('platform', PlatformsAPI.getPlatformResponse)
}

export default useGetPlatforms
```

And the Code for my component as below

```
import { useGetVehicleBrands } from '../../../hooks/RQHooks'

function VehicleBrands() {
    const { data, isLoading } = useGetVehicleBrands()
    console.log('data', data.platform)

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {data.platform.map((item) =><h1>{item}</h1>)}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default PlatformComponent
```

The error I'm getting in my above code is that I couldn't access the platform property from the data. Typescript throwing error saying that the platform property not found. Only the property from the AxiosResponse is shown. How to accomplish that the typescript know that data is the type of PlatformResponse. Kindly help to accomplish it.

[image]

Comment: add error log as code block in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get a `data` property from `react-query` that contains the unwrapped promise from whatever your `queryFn` returns.

an `AxiosResponse` contains what you're seeing in your screenshot -  `data`, `headers`, `statusText` etc.

Your actual `data` is inside the `data` property, so you'd need:

```
data.data.platform
```

The first `data` being the one from react-query, the second one being the one from axios.

If you don't need to store request meta-data like headers in your queryCache, it is best to unwrap it inside the queryFn:

```
useQuery(
  'platform',
   () => PlatformsAPI.getPlatformResponse().then(response => response.data))
)
```

you can also do that inside your PlatformsAPI if you want.